# UINavigationBar Transition

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Currently, I am having an issue with the transition of two navigation bars. The root view has a transparent navigation bar, while the other navigation bar is opaque with a bar tint color. This is what is currently going on: 
https://youtu.be/xfpNnjfOMRc. As you can see, the transparent navbar blinks. The transparent nav bar has this line of code: `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)`.

To go about solving this issue, I added this block of code to the second view controller (with the bar tint color):

```
override func willMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMoveToParentViewController(parent)
    if parent == nil {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    }
}
```

Now however, this happens: https://youtu.be/oMLL0v9_9Yc. When the back button is pressed, the nav bar of the second view controller is rendered transparent, solving the issue above. However, this is not the ideal solution. I simply want a smooth transition between the two nav bars. Ideas?